# Static files not working in Iframe in production mode django

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-staticfiles

In production mode my django project1 working fine.

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'mysite' ,'static') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite',  "static"),
  '/var/www/static/',
]
```

I ran this project in localhost:8000

And my different project(project2) which is running into localhost:8001

I want to show project1's home page in project2 using iframe or embed 
but project1's static files not working here.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

and set debug to true, if you set debug to false then run `manage.py --insecure`. The reason: If you set debug to true then you server will take care the staticfiles and not the Django server